# NavigationBar VisualStudio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Hoje iniciei um projeto em C# e percebi que na barra de navegação, quando eu clico em um controle eu sou direcionado ao designer do .aspx, e não é exibido os eventos que o controle possui como na linguagem VB.Net.

[image: NavigationBar]

Eu só consigo ir até o evento caso eu abra as propriedades do controle, ai eu clico no icone Events, e em seguida no respectivo evento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe se é possível resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta é a *Navigation Bar*, e realmente ela é diferente entre o VB.Net e o C#

No VB.Net ela pode ser usada para escolher os eventos disponíveis em um controle, já no C# ela pode ser usada apenas para navegar entre os métodos existentes em seu código, então a forma de se navegar pelos eventos é mesmo pela janela de propriedades.

Eu não sei dizer o motivo exato de serem diferentes, mas diria que isso foi intencional devido a diferenças na forma como o código que trata eventos é gerado pelo VB.Net e C#, no VB.Net o keyword `Handles` instrui o compilador a gerar o código de tratamento de eventos, enquanto que no C# ele é incluído pela IDE geralmente no método `InitializeComponent()` ou diretamente nas Tags no caso do WebForms.